# Java Scanner hasNext(String) method do not match sometimes

Tags: parsing, java.util.scanner

I was trying to use Java Scanner `hasNext` method, but I got strange results. Maybe my problem is very obvious, but why the this simple simple expression `"[a-zA-Z']+"` not working for words like this: "points. anything, supervisor,". I have tried this `"[\\w']+"` too.

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> getDocumentWordStructureFromPath(File file) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> dictionary = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (lineScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(lineScanner.nextLine());
            while (scanner.hasNext("[\\w']+")) {
                String word = scanner.next().toLowerCase();
                if (word.length() > 2) {
                    int count = dictionary.containsKey(word) ? dictionary.get(word).intValue() + 1 : 1;
                    dictionary.put(word, new Integer(count));
                }
            }
            scanner.close();
        }
        //scanner.useDelimiter(DELIMITER);
        lineScanner.close();

        return dictionary;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression should be like this `[^a-zA-z]+` as you need to separate all the things that are not letters:

```
// previous code...
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(lineScanner.nextLine()).useDelimiter("[^a-zA-z]+");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String word = scanner.next().toLowerCase();
        // ...your other code
    }
}
// ... after code
```

**EDIT-- Why is not working with the hasNext(String) method??**

This line:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(lineScanner.nextLine());
```

what it really does is to compile a whitespce pattern for you, so if you have for example this test line `"Hello World. A test, ok."` it will deliver you this tokens:

- Hello
- World.
- A
- test,
- ok.

Then if you use `scanner.hasNext("[a-ZA-Z]+")` you're asking the scanner `if there is a token that match your pattern`, for this example it will state `true` for the first token:

- Hello (as this is the frist token that matches the pattern you specified)

For the next token (**World.**) `it doesn't match the pattern` so it will simply `fail` and `scanner.hasNext("[a-ZA-Z]+")` will return `false` so it will never work for words preceded by any character who's not a letter. You get it?

Now... hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much @Angel Rodriguez this is a good solution, but I don't know why is not working with the hasnext(String) function.

Comment: Ok i got your point, i've edited post... and i explain why it doesn't work... hope it helps...

Comment: thank you very much I have got it. Thank you very much for your help. +1 for the detailed explanation.